# Repeated tween animation in Android: some issue

Tags: android, repeat, tween

I tried-out for repeated animation in Android with the below code but failed to do so.

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
a.reset();
ImageView rText = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
a.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART); 
a.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
rText.startAnimation(a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare

```
   android:repeatCount="infinite"
```

In your animation.xml

then in your code

```
   ImageView rText = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
   Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
   rText.startAnimation(a);
```